# How to install node package in Laravel Mix correctly?

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have clear Laravel 5.7 installation and I need to install izimodal package

So I have installed by `npm install izimodal`.

For the next step, I initialized this package in my `/resources/js/bootstrap.js` like:

```
import iziModal from 'izimodal/js/iziModal';
$.fn.iziModal = iziModal;
```

and run `npm run dev` to compile app.js

At this stage, the package was successfully imported and working but I missing CSS part of izimodal... How can I correctly initialize this package with CSS? I have tried this code in my `webpack.mix.js` but it does not work:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/izimodal/css/iziModal.css', 'resources/css');

mix.styles([
    'resources/css/reset.css',
    'resources/css/style.css'
    ], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Comment: You only copy it's css file, but you don't reference it in your `styles()` call when assembling public `app.css` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just added to my app.scss

```
// npm-package
@import "~izimodal/css/iziModal.css";
// Custom CSS
@import "../css/reset.css";
@import "../css/style.css";
```